# Radius of an image not in the image plane due to diffraction?

Tags: optics

When viewing an image in the image plane the radius of the image (assuming it is circular) is given by the radius of the Airy disc. But let's say we are not viewing it in the image plane, but in another plane. What is its radius 'spot' in this case? (see digram below)[image]

I can see two possibilites:

1. Diffraction does not affect the size of this spot and thus it can be found using normal geomatry. In this case the size of the spot would overlay any diffraction.
2. Diffraction does affect the size of this spot (in which case it would be Fresnel diffraction).

Which of these is correct, and why? (In other words, how do we correctly find the radius of the spot when it does not lie in the image plane?)

Comment: If the defocus is a small percentage, you can get an approximate answer by expanding the pattern along the geometric "cone" of light.  However, the actual pattern continually changes and must be calculated based on the equivalent propagation distance in free space (no lens) using the full (ugly) equations based on wavelet production across the full wavefront.